# mysql btree index on InnoDB tables?

Tags: mysql

Do InnoDB  tables already contain a b tree? Or was i reading something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innodb tables have a special kind of primary key index called a clustered b-tree index which can make well a well designed innodb table very fast to query.

following resources may be of interest:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/

Answer (score 0):

should be b+ tree, not b tree
according to: [this](http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/btree-index-structures-in-innodb/)